# why sympy count_ops() fail on this result from integration?

Tags: sympy

I use sympy's `count_opt` as a way to estimate size (leaf count) of `antiderivative` returned by `integrate`.

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I found it fails on some expressions. This is using sympy 1.1.1 on

```
   Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
   [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
```

Here is an example

```
from sympy import *
x,n,a = symbols('x n a')
integrand = x**n*log(a*x)
anti= integrate(integrand,x)
count_ops(anti)
```

and now

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", 
    line 2473, in count_ops
    if a.is_Rational:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_Rational'
```

Something about this result it does not like

```
>>> anti
Piecewise((None, Eq(n, -1)), (n*x*x**n*log(a)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) + 
  n*x*x**n*log(x)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) + x*x**n*log(a)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) + 
  x*x**n*log(x)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) - x*x**n/(n**2 + 2*n + 1), True))
```

Is this a known issue? Why does it happen? Is this a bug? Should I report it? How?

The above is on linux Manjaro  17.1 XFCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `count_ops` does not expect to see `None`, which sometimes appears in a `Piecewise` object. I'd say this is a bug. It was already [reported on SymPy issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12994).

A workaround is to pass `conds='none'` to `integrate`, which will cause it to ignore the special case n=-1 and return a single expression,

```
n*x*x**n*log(a)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) + n*x*x**n*log(x)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) + x*x**n*log(a)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) + x*x**n*log(x)/(n**2 + 2*n + 1) - x*x**n/(n**2 + 2*n + 1)
```

Then `count_ops` works correctly.

```
anti = integrate(integrand, x, conds='none')
count_ops(anti)   # 49
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I remember now. I the one who actually reported this a year or so ago. I forgot about it. Why is it not fixed yet? Ok,. will add an exception handler.